# Seeding fails when property hiding

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, properties, entity-framework-6

This is more of a thought exercise than anything. Consider the following classes:

```
public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    public object Id { get; set; }

    private string name;
    [Required]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private DateTime? createdDate;
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate
    {
        get { return createdDate ?? DateTime.UtcNow; }
        set { createdDate = value; }
    }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public Byte[] Version { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity<T> : Entity, IEntity<T>
{
    [Key]
    new public T Id
    {
        get { return base.Id != null ? (T)base.Id : default(T); }
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }
}
```

`Entity<T>` hides the the `Id` property on `Entity` replacing it with the right type. If I create an entity from this:

```
public class Foo : Entity<int>
{
    ...
}
```

And add it to the context:

```
public virtual IDbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
```

Entity Framework happily creates the appropriate table. All the core EF functions work just fine: I can query, save, update, delete, etc.

However, if I try to seed:

```
context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(
    r => r.Name,
    new Foo { ... },
    new Foo { ... },
    ...
);
```

And run `update-database`. The first time, seeding works correctly. On each subsequent run, however, seeding will raise an exception:

```
Running Seed method.
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TypeExtensions.GetAnyProperty(Type type, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass9`1.<GetKeyProperties>b__8(EdmMember km)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](DbSet`1 set, IEnumerable`1 identifyingProperties, InternalSet`1 internalSet, TEntity[] entities)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](IDbSet`1 set, Expression`1 identifierExpression, TEntity[] entities)
   ...
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Ambiguous match found.
```

Now, I understand *why* this is happening. EF is using reflection and getting two results for `Id`, one from `Entity` and one from `Entity<T>`. It's unable to determine which to use, and fails. My question is: is there anything I can do to help remove the ambiguity?

For what it's worth, I'm running EF 6.1.3.

Comment: no other configuration involved?

Comment: Nope. This is all there is to it.

Comment: Does the created table ends up with two Id columns?

Comment: No, just one column.

Comment: Ah, I would have thought that you would have needed a `[NotMapped]` or `Ignore`.

Comment: Nope, and that's the semi-frustrating bit. Everything works smooth as silk except seeding, and even then, it only fails on updates, not adds. Almost feels like a bug in EF, but since it is really an edge case, I don't expect it to be fixed any time soon or at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could...avoid hiding a property when it involves a key property. :)

In any case, if you look at their source code, when `AddOrUpdate` finds an existing entity using the given properties (e.g. `r => r.Name`), it first replaces the key properties, before using `Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity)` to update the non-key properties. The problem is that it gets the key properties by getting a list of property *names* and filtering -- `.Where(p => p.Name == name)` -- the list given by [`GetRuntimeProperties()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.runtimereflectionextensions.getruntimeproperties(v=vs.110).aspx), which includes inherited properties.

Maybe another solution is to get the EF team to change that? Seems like a bit of an edge case.

Comment: It is a bit of an edge case, I admit. The reason I'm attempting this is that I need to be able to work with a non-generic interface and still reference the Id property.